# CSS question: How to fix several rendering issues on http://www.fareham.ac.uk

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging, firefox

I tested the front page of the Fareham College web site in the most popular browsers using the [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/) tool, which highlighted the following issues:

- [Windows XP Internet Explorer 9.0](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/683/wxpie9000.jpg/)
- [Windows XP Internet Explorer 8.0](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/801/wxpie8000.jpg/)
- [Windows XP Internet Explorer 6.0](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/wxpie6000.jpg/) (less important)
- [Windows XP Firefox 4.0](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/196/wxpff4000.jpg/)
- [Windows XP Firefox 3.5](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/wxpff3500.jpg/)
- [Windows XP Firefox 3.0](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/221/wxpff3000or.jpg/)

The site should look like this: [Windows XP Internet Explorer 7.0](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/wxpie7000.jpg/)

Can anyone provides solutions to any of the above problems? It seemed sensible to lump these together in a single thread, rather than posting a separate question for each issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind highlighting what is actually the "problem" and how the site is supposed to look?

Comment: Apologies. Added link to image of how the site should look. The problems are isolated to the top panel and footer regions of the page.

Comment: Could you provide a URL to a live sample instead?

Comment: http://www.fareham.ac.uk

Comment: Haha, I just realised the URL was actually in the question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on the accuracy of Browser Labs, I've tested your site in Firefox 4 and mine is fine, so I think you could probably ignore that one

The code in IE seems to be rendering differently too, seems to me (using the Developer tools) that there is possibly a closing tag closing somethign a bit too early, I'd suggest fixing these errors; 
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fareham.ac.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

And seeing if that fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to whittle the validation errors down to one. Now to tackle the CSS layout problems...

Comment: Fixing those errors seem to have resolved the footer issue in IE.
I've checked it in IE7, 8 and 9, as well as Firefox and I don't see any issue - I'm not sure how accurate the Browser Labs stuff is. 
I had an issue with IE6 before on Browser Labs, which I couldn't pick up on a mchine running a genuine IE6.

I can supply screenshots if you require them

Comment: Thanks for your time. That's marvellous! Most of the errors were caused by missing alt attributes on the social media images in the footer. Why would this throw the layout of the page off though?

Comment: I didn't read through all of the errors on the validator, but my guess is that there was a missing tag, IE <div>..... but no closing </div> for that particular element.
Although another error could of potentially been screwing things - IE is pretty pedantic when it comes to errors, the smallest thing can put IE out of place, especially with Javascript, all it takes is a missing semi-colon or comma and IE won't like it!